# Can I use gnosis-safe.io with custom Gnosis Safe contracts?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I want to modify a Gnosis Safe contract so that the owners of the safe are determined by who holds a specific NFT.

E.g. if I own the NFT, I'm a Gnosis Safe contract owner. If I send the NFT to another person, that person will become the owner and I will cease to be.

My question is - if I modify a Gnosis Safe contract, and deploy it to say `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000645D`, will I be able to access and interact with the contract through the existing https://gnosis-safe.io user interface?

E.g. by visiting `https://gnosis-safe.io/app/eth:0x000000000000000000000000000000000000645D/balances`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you want be able to do that, and even if you deploy your own infrastructure using https://github.com/gnosis/safe-infrastructure it probably not work as the backend is not prepared to work with that logic.

For that to work you would need to refactor both the Gnosis Safe contract and the Gnosis Safe Tx Service.